# Show to the user that there are more stuff in a ScrollView on Android

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a fragment with a ScrollView. When there are more things to be shown I'd like to show something to the users (an arrow?) to let they know that they can scroll to see something more.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: If any answer was useful, please mark as accepted ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus)
{
    if(child_of_scrollView.getMeasuredHeight() > oScrollView.getMeasuredHeight())
        //Show some arrow image or something you like to show
}
```

Comment: Also see [ssantos' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19243664/199364), for more details - `ScrollView` inside `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 6):

You can make your scrollview' scrollbar visible all the time, instead of only if the user tries to scroll down/up.

You can do it by adding `android:fadeScrollbars="false"` into your definition of your ScrollView XML

Comment: A variation on this is to force it visible when the view first appears, then fade away after several seconds. This gives user a hint that it is a scrollable area, then reverts to Android's uncluttered design where the scrollbar isn't visible if user is not scrolling.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there's no out-of-the-box implementation for this. You could just have your `ScrollView` inside a `RelativeLayout`, and change visibility of an `ImageView` (your arrow), which would be on top of `ScrollView`, depending on wether or not the scroll has scrolled to the bottom.

Comment: Because an arrow looks like something to click on, consider making it clickable, and have it scroll by some amount each time. While its scrolling make sure scrollbar is visible. Consider also setting a longer fade time on scrollbar, so it stays around for a second or two after arrow is clicked - giving user hint that this is a regular scrollable area; they don't *have* to click the arrow.

Answer (score 2):

Some time ago I had a similar need to yours. What I wanted was that when the activity is displayed, automatically scroll was made from the bottom to up so the user could see there were more items available. The way I did it was using the ViewTreeObserver. Below an example of how I got it.

```
    private ScrollView mScroll;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);

        mScroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);

        ViewTreeObserver vto = mScroll.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {

                mScroll.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

                int scrollHeight = mScroll.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredHeight();
                mScroll.scrollTo(0, scrollHeight);
            }
        }); 
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                mScroll.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
            }

        }, 800);

    }
```

I hope it will helpful for someone ;)

Comment: An interesting idea. Important to test on users; this technique might be mildly annoying after user has seen the scrolling enough times to know the view scrolls. In general its preferable to avoid motion that isn't initiated by user, especially of the whole content area. Personally I favor other "hint" techniques.